# .Net Core 2.1 Api passing same header parameter multiple times

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-apicontroller

In the Api controller, one action takes a header parameters and for testing this action i'm trying to pass same parameter multiple time..

expected behavior is that this parameter should be overwritten or take the first value.
but the actual result is that i'm receiving a string contains combines all of them (',' separated)..

[image]

[image]

any help please.

Answer (score 2):

> expected behavior is that this parameter should be overwritten or take the first value.

This is not expected behavior defined by the [HTTP standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), in which multiple header fields with the same name are allowed:

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

Comment: Thanks, what i meant by "expected behavior" is what i need, so is there a way to do override or take first parameter if it passed multiple time, rather than manually check for duplication?

Comment: @BassemMamar I think you would need to do something like `value.Split(",")[0]` or watch and remove duplicates before posting on the client if you have control over that.